# Do i need any special configuration when i use MQTT 5.0 with node red?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I have an working project where, with the MQTT-IN node, i subscribe to a local Mosquitto Broker. But when i want to change to MQTT Version 5 it doens't work. On every other Subscriber (mqttx) it was working after just changing the version in the options somewhere. But after changing it on the configuration-node it doesn't connect anymore. Do i have to change anything else to get it working or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the broker supports MQTT v5 then changing the setting in the broker config node and it will make use of the MQTT v5 features.

If it's not connecting you need to look at the Node-RED logs and the broker logs.